# Hash Code Used In Map Keys

Tags: hashcode

How is hash code generated when we use sobject as map keys in salesforce? As per the documentation, the hash code uses sobject field values to generate hash key but what if there are more than 200 fields in an object? Does it uses all the field values to build hash code? Or is there any other data used in hash keys?

Answer (score 1):

From a brief experiment of querying various numbers of fields (up to 281 of them anyway) for an SObject and assuming [System.hashCode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_system_system_hashcode) that works on:

> The object to get the hash code for. This parameter can be of any
>   type, including values or object references, such as sObjects or
>   user-defined types.

is the logic used for map keys then it does appear that all non-null fields are considered because adding or removing a field made a difference to the computed value.

Calculating the `hashCode` value where there are hundreds of fields will obviously take hundreds of times more work than calculating the `hashCode` for a single field. So that is one reason to use the SObject `ID` as a key (the conventional practice in Apex) rather than the whole SObject as a key.

Comment: Hi @keith, I did some research on this and found that when we use sobject as a map key or in sets, the uniqueness is not maintainted by its record fields, but salesforce uses sobject instances. For example, if we have two instances that are of same record, then map will have two keys, one for each sobject instance.

Comment: @HemendraSinghBhati That hasn't been my experience. It is (except in contrived test cases) hard to get instances with identical fields. Using a simple key - such as the ID - is the way to go in my view.